# Big-O and equals sign, abuse of notation

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation):

> The statement "f(x) is O(g(x))" as defined above is usually written as
>   f(x) = O(g(x)). Some consider this to be an abuse of notation, since
>   the use of the equals sign could be misleading as it suggests a
>   symmetry that this statement does not have. As de Bruijn says, O(x) =
>   O(x^2) is true but O(x^2) = O(x) is not

I understand the formal definition but not what de Bruin says. Im puzzeled by trying to understand what O(x) = O(x^2) or even O(x) is O(x^2) really means.

Intuitively I would read it as "The class of functions with complexity x is the same as the  class of functions with complexity x^2".  But that does not make sense.

The [wikipedia talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aBig_O_notation#.22is_an_element_of.22_vs_.22equals.22) page does not help much either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Intuitively I would read it as "The class of functions with complexity x is the same as the class of functions with complexity x^2". But that does not make sense.

Yes, and that is why people don't like the notation with the equals sign.

It should read as "The class of functions with complexity x is included in the class of functions with complexity x^2" or "A function with a linear upper bound for complexity is also a function with a quadratic upper complexity bound" (where of course the quadratic bound is not very tight).

Comment: yepp, ∈ or ⊆ would be probably better.

Comment: Re: ∈ or ⊆  It says as much on the Wikipedia page, too (+1 for being able to type that...)

Answer (score 0):

In math, '=' is usually expected represent "equality", and should be an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).  This means it should be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

> As de Bruijn says, O(x) = O(x^2) is true but O(x^2) = O(x) is not

means the relation is not symmetric.