# Why is "=" used to expressing time-complexity of algorithms and not "∈"?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

I use big-o here. Let f(n) and g(n) be two functions with the same time-complexity that is equal to O(n).

By definition(When using "=" to explain the time-complexity) this kind of reasoning could be true:

```
IF f(n)=O(n) AND g(n)=O(n) THEN f(n)=g(n)
```

But as we know, two functions with the same growth rates are not necessarily the same.

To avoiding these kind of mismatches, why O(n) is not defined as the set of any function that its time-complexity is O(n)?

```
O(n)=O(f(n))=O(g(n))={n, f(n), g(n), ...}
f(n)∈O(n)
g(n)∈O(n)
```

Comment: Source for your first claim?  I would not consider that to be true.

Comment: [Big O Notation “is element of” or “is equal”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066004/big-o-notation-is-element-of-or-is-equal). [Big-O and equals sign, abuse of notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077351/big-o-and-equals-sign-abuse-of-notation). [What are the rules for equals signs with big-O and little-o?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86076/what-are-the-rules-for-equals-signs-with-big-o-and-little-o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O(*n*) is, in fact, defined exactly as you suggest. The frequent use of = instead of ∈ is just an abuse of notation; but it's convenient, and does not cause any ambiguity in practice.